# How to get a quoted printable string in golang

Tags: go

How to get a quoted printable string created according to » RFC2045, section 6.7. in golang

PHP equivalent is "quoted_printable_encode ( string $str )"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [standard quotedprintable package](https://godoc.org/mime/quotedprintable) to encode the string:

```
...

import (
    "bytes"
    "mime/quotedprintable"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

...

func toQuotedPrintable(s string) (string, error) {
    var ac bytes.Buffer
    w := quotedprintable.NewWriter(&ac)
    _, err := w.Write([]byte(s))
    if err != nil {
        return "", errors.Wrap(err, "write")
    }
    err = w.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return "", errors.Wrap(err, "close")
    }
    return ac.String(), nil
}
```

Comment: Your example is missing the package import statement which brings that `quotedprintable` symbol into the scope.

Comment: i just put the function only

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to highlight: as present, your answer is only 50% useful (or lower).

Comment: The use of the non-standard errors package is a distraction to the answer (thank you @Hugh for adding the import path to the errors package in an edit).

Comment: Definitely agree with @CeriseLimón on this - there's absolutely no reason to go outside the stdlib for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Clear example with [mime/quotedprintable](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/quotedprintable):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "mime/quotedprintable"
)

func main() {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    text := "Möchten Sie ein paar Äpfel?"
    if err := quotedPrintableEncode(buf, text); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(buf.String())
    }
}

func quotedPrintableEncode(buf *bytes.Buffer, text string) error {
    qp := quotedprintable.NewWriter(buf)
    if _, err := qp.Write([]byte(text)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := qp.Close(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

The above example will output:

```
Möchten Sie ein paar Äpfel?
M=C3=B6chten Sie ein paar =C3=84pfel?
```

Also look at [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/UGy5EG-0Fb1).